# Extract Esri Open Data catalog metadata in R

Tags: r, arcgis-online, metadata

I am looking to pull metadata information from an [Esri Open Data site](https://catalogue-hrm.opendata.arcgis.com/search?tags=Halifax%20Open%20Data) (aka GeoHub). Each dataset (i.e. [HRM Parks](https://catalogue-hrm.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/HRM::hrm-parks/explore)) has non-spatial metadata about the dataset (i.e. published date, tags, etc.). When I pull this information from the layer it is not available. I am wondering if there is a metadata option for the catalog, and or catalog entities? I am able to pull layer metadata programatically in R using the `arcpullr` package

`arcpullr::get_layer_info("https://services2.arcgis.com/11XBiaBYA9Ep0yNJ/arcgis/rest/services/HRM_Parks_2/FeatureServer/0")`

Is there a way to programatically in R to pull metadata for the entire catalog, or catalog datasets?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any function in that package to get the whole catalog info, but there appears to be some web API endpoints that return a list of layers, and that can return in JSON format, which you can then use. You'll need the `rjson` package installed for these examples:

Your server appears to have 388 feature endpoints:

```
> root = "https://services2.arcgis.com/11XBiaBYA9Ep0yNJ/arcgis/rest/services"
> services = rjson::fromJSON(file=paste0(root,"?f=json"))
> length(services$services)
[1] 388
```

Then you can get individual item info from the name. For example the 120th item is:

```
> n120 = services$services[[120]]$name
> n120
[1] "NSPW_HRM_Service_Exchange_Boundary_2006_"
```

You can then build the URL for getting the info from an item and return its info in json format:

```
> info_url = paste0(root, "/", n120, "/FeatureServer/info/itemInfo?f=json")
> info120 = rjson::fromJSON(file=info_url) 
> info120$extent
[1] -64.01912  44.56196 -63.32368  44.86598
```

Most of the 388 layers here appear to be `type="FeatureServer"` except for a few `SceneServer` types - there's probably a different API for these and you may need to change the `info_url` in the above to get their info. This is the sort of fiddly stuff you'd hope a package would do for you, so maybe `arcpullr` does this? I don't know. It seems that if you put `SceneServer` in the URL you get back "scene info" (with lots of layers) but you can also use `FeatureServer` to get a structure with an extent (of all the layers? Don't know).

Read up on the various ArcGIS REST APIs for more. I'm mostly working from:

https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/get-started-with-the-services-directory.htm

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman, this is helpful, but does not provide the date related components that I was hoping to find...will keep digging. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: If you could edit your Q to say exactly what you are after, with an example, that would be good.

Comment: Sorry, I felt like I did identify specifically, but here it is: non-spatial metadata about the dataset (i.e. published date, tags, etc.). The publish date is something that is not available via the solution provided

Comment: I've found an API point that returns the "lastEditDate","schemaLastEditDate" and "dataLastEditDate" - and they are all Nov 23 for this data set, but I can't find an API point that returns the published date of 2017....aaargh...

Comment: Thanks Spacedman, you validated that I am not crazy, thanks for looking at this!